# Convert a python list having a mix of unicode values and floating numbers

Tags: python, unicode, xlrd

So I am reading values from an excel and storing inside a list. But by default, it stored strings as unicode strings and numbers as floats. I want to convert unicode strings into normal strings and float to integer. How do I do that?

Here's my list:

```
import xlrd 
wb = xlrd.open_workbook("test.xlsx")
firstsheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0)
rows =1
rowvalues = []
while(rows <= (firstsheet.nrows)-1):
     rowvalues.extend(firstsheet.row_values(rows)) 
     rows+=1
print rowvalues
```

Output:

```
[121090999.0, 3454554455.0, u'Shantharam', 121090999.0, 5645.0, u'Puranik']
```

What I need:

```
[ 121090999,  3454554455,  'Shantharam', 121090999,  5645,  'Puranik' ]
```

Comment: I guess Shantharam & Puranik should still be within `'`, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [isinstance](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#isinstance) to check the type of the variable

```
rows = [121090999.0, 3454554455.0, u'Shantharam', 121090999.0, 5645.0, u'Puranik']
def convert_rows(rows):
    for kk,vv in enumerate(rows):        
        if isinstance(vv,float):
            rows[kk] = int(vv)
        if isinstance(vv,unicode):
            rows[kk] = vv.encode('ascii')
    return rows
print( convert_rows(rows) )
# prints [121090999, 3454554455L, 'Shantharam', 121090999, 5645, 'Puranik']
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is the `list` comprehension to convert items in list to:

1. `str` if it is `unicode`
2. `int` if it is `float`
3. Else, append as it is:

> Sample Example:

```
>>> my_list = [121090999.0, 3454554455.0, u'Shantharam', 121090999.0, 5645.0, u'Puranik']
>>> [str(item) if isinstance(item, unicode) else int(item) if isinstance(item,float) else item for item in my_list]
# Output: [121090999, 3454554455, 'Shantharam', 121090999, 5645, 'Puranik']
```

However, instead of converting list to desired format, you should make these checks (*if* conditions) at the time you are extending `rowvalues`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a short script that should do the trick:

```
l=[121090999.0, 3454554455.0, u'Shantharam', 121090999.0, 5645.0, u'Puranik'];
i=0
for i in range(len(l)-1):
        if isinstance(l[i], float):
             l[i]=int(l[i])
        else:
             l[i]=str(l[i])
print(l)
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is the list comprehension code which does exactly what you want:

```
   [int(d) if isinstance(d, float) else str(d) if isinstance(d, unicode) else d for d in my_list]
```

Run this code on your `my_list` and you'll get the following response:

```
    new_list = [121090999, 3454554455, 'Shantharam', 121090999, 5645, 'Puranik']
```

You can verify the datatype of the elements as:

```
    type(new_list[-1])  # <type 'str'>
    type(new_list[-2])  # <type 'int'>
```